# MySQL: How can I trim a prefix keyword in the table column?

Tags: mysql

I use a keyword `m` to represent a post from a `member` while an `u` from an `user`,

So the post `owner id` will have something like this,
`m-1`, `m-2`, `u-1`, etc.

`m-1` is `member id` 1

`m-2` is `member id` 2

`u-1` is `user id` 1

Here is the table post,

```
needle_id   needle_title    needle_content  needle_published    owner_id    pg_id   
    1       a               xxx status      1                   m-1         39      
    2       b               xxx status      1                   m-2         39  
    3       c               xxx status      1                   m-3         39  
    4       d               xxx status      1                   u-1         39  
    5       e               xxx status      1                   m-1         39
```

and the table member,

```
mem_id  mem_screenname      mem_email           mem_key     cat_id
1       Member one          a@sample.com        xxx         1
2       Member two          b@sample.com        xxx         1
3       Member three        c@sample.com        xxx         1
```

Here is my query,

```
SELECT
n.needle_id as needleID,
n.needle_title as needleTitle,
n.needle_content as needleContent,
n.needle_published as needleApproved,
n.mem_id as needleOwnerID,
n.needle_created as needleCreated,

m.mem_screenname as needleOwnerScreenname,
m.mem_email as needleOwnerEmail,
m.mem_key as needleOwnerKey,
m.cat_name as needleOwnerType

FROM root_string_needles AS n

    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        mm.mem_id,
        mm.mem_screenname,
        mm.mem_email,
        mm.mem_key,
        ccmm.cat_name

        FROM root_members_cfm  AS mm

        LEFT JOIN root_category_members AS ccmm
        ON ccmm.cat_id = mm.cat_id
    ) AS m 
    ON m.mem_id = n.owner_id 

WHERE n.pg_id = '39'

AND m.mem_screenname IS NOT NULL
AND n.needle_published != '0'

ORDER BY n.needle_created DESC
```

I'm stuck at `ON m.mem_id = n.owner_id` because I use **prefix** for the `owner id` and they won't match.

So how can I trim the prefix in the column of `owner id` so that the column `mem id` can match `owner id`?

Comment: That is not the way to do it. You should consider having two columns, `owner_id` and `mem_id`, and use referential integrity between your tables and join against the correct column in your queries.

Comment: Mikael you should post that as an answer. You're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

@Mikael has the righ answer.  To actually trim the data you can use the MySQL mid function:

```
MID(owner_id,3,2)
```

You can also find the dash (-) and then extract all data after the dash.